# Loop through table and print in specific column order

Tags: python, sqlite, for-loop

I have a table of videos with `title`, `release` and `synopsis` among other fields. I'd like to loop over each row and print columns in a specific order:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("videos.db")
cur = con.cursor()

videos = "SELECT * FROM videos"

for videos in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM videos;'):
    print("title:",videos[2])
    print("release:",videos[3])
    print("description:",videos[4])
    print("-" * 10)
```

But this is incorrect as :

1. I need to see what columns are printed instead of remembering index numbers as they are subject to change as I update the table, and
2. I don't think tuples are the correct output.

Intended result:

```
title: video 1
release: 2022-01-01
description: video 1 description
---------
title: video 2
release: 2022-01-02
description: video 2 description
---------
```

The end goal is to export each as separate XML file.

Comment: Can we see what `videos`' output is like ?

Comment: The database is a test db so this is the current output, other columns have dummy data like this. I've updated to outline the whole py file.

Comment: [mre] [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055)

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, the first element of the array returned, so `videos` in your case, contains the list of the columns returned by you SQL request.

So here's something you could do :

```py
videos = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM videos;')

# Get the index of the columns
title_index = videos[0].index("title");
release_index = videos[0].index("release");
description_index = videos[0].index("description_index");

for video in videos:
    # And use those indexes to get the data
    print("title:",videos[title_index])
    print("release:",videos[release_index])
    print("description:",videos[description_index])
    print("-" * 10)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error 'TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: Well.. that's why I wanted to see exactly what the output of videos is like :/

Comment: I misunderstood, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{path}", line 29, in <module>
    title_index = videos[0].index("title_index");
TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable